# Pytest tmpdir_factory threw an error "Expected binary or unicode string, got local"

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, pytest, fixtures

I'm using `pytest` to do testing on splitting data into train, val, test set for machine learning problem. I create temporary files using `tmpdir_factory`, but it threw me an error something like `TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got local('/tmp/pytest/pytest-4/test_folder0/train.tfrecord')`. Here is my code:

Inside `conftest.py`:

```
DATA_FOLDER = 'test_folder'

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def train_dataset(tmpdir_factory):
    return tmpdir_factory.mktemp(DATA_FOLDER).join('train.tfrecord')

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def val_dataset(tmpdir_factory):
    return tmpdir_factory.mktemp(DATA_FOLDER).join('val.tfrecord')

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def test_dataset(tmpdir_factory):
    return tmpdir_factory.mktemp(DATA_FOLDER).join('test.tfrecord')
```

Inside the test file:

```
def test_split(train_dataset, val_dataset, test_dataset):
    # the arguments of split_function refer to the path where the splitting results is written
    split_function(train_dataset, val_dataset, test_dataset)
    """continue with assert functions"""
```

Can anyone please help? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tmpdir_factory` fixture methods return a [py.path.local](https://py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/path.html) object, that encapsulates a path (a bit simular to `pathlib.Path`). These method calls can therefore be chained to manipulate paths, as is done in your fixtures using `mktemp().join()`. To get back a `str` path from the result, you have to explicitely convert the `py.path.local` to `str`:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def train_dataset(tmpdir_factory):
    return str(tmpdir_factory.mktemp(DATA_FOLDER).join('train.tfrecord'))
```

As your tested functions don't know about `py.path.local`, converting paths created by `tmpdir_factory` back to `str` is generally the way to use this fixture.